# Laravel Configuration (No such file directory ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

[image: Homestead.yaml file and the CMD]

Hello, I wanted to try creating a Laravel Application and I am really new to this.
I tried all the best I can to analyze and implement the solutions of other people but to no success.

So I have followed the methods in configuring the Laravel App.
The ssh key has also been created in the homekey file as seen from the Homestead.yaml file, I edited it.

But when I try to do 'vagrant up'.
This error message begin to show.
It seems looking for the directory of .homestead but even I can't find it.
I don't know what step am I overlooking.

Comment: Where is your Homestead.yaml file saved? Also, try `homestead up` instead of `vagrant up`.

Comment: My Homestead.yaml file is saved in the Homestead folder

Comment: I just realized you're on Windows. Have a look at this: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/laravel-homestead-on-windows